# What gamepads can be used in Magicka?

Tags: pc, magicka

I just bought Magicka and want to play it on my computer with my girlfriend. Buying a gamepad seems to be the only option. I've never owned one, so I have no idea what kind the game supports or what the interface looks like.

**How do I know if a gamepad is compatible with Magicka?** I already have USB keyboards, a Wiimote with nunchuk, an unrooted Android phone, and a couple of other computers (too weak to play the game). Could I use any of those?

What are my options?

Comment: I believe most USB gamepads should work, but I would suggest picking up a wired Xbox 360 controller - many Windows games with controller support will *only* support this type of gamepad (without resorting to custom drivers or other modifications).

Comment: @agent86 Magicka has special requirements because of the way input is done for that game. That said, this is still a shopping recommendation and thus off topic.

Comment: @StrixVaria: I'm not asking what would be the best to buy, but what is supported by the game. Definitely not a shopping recommendation, which would be "Which gamepad should I buy?" or "Which gamepad is the best for my situation?".

Comment: @Mark The line is fuzzy at best. My close vote stands. We'll see how others vote.

Comment: @StrixVaria I wouldn't consider it a shopping recommendation. He isn't simply asking for recommendations, he's asking for what will work from a technical perspective.

'How do I know if a "gamepad" works with Magicka?'

(lists what input devices he has) 'Could I use any of that?'

He is curious about his options are.

Comment: @Lemmings19, I think the title is either a shopping rec or a list, neither of which work well here. The bolded part of the question, I think, is a better way to ask it: the best answer would explain what Magicka requires and how to compare that against a gamepad's features ... particularly when compared to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/12682/8366), which covers the general controllers-for-PC case.

Comment: I used to play Magicka with my DualShock 3 but have since moved to the DualShock 4 after it was released, however these controllers need third-party drivers as they have to be converted into XInput so that the computer detects them as an Xbox controller. The drivers I used  were motioninjoy for DS3 and DS4Tools for the DS4 which can be found easily by a Google search.

Answer (score 2):

Magicka supports XInput-compatible gamepads (also known as Xbox 360-compatible). If your gamepad uses DirectInput instead of XInput (i.e. it is not compatible with Xbox 360), you can use [x360ce](https://code.google.com/p/x360ce/) to make it work with Magicka.

Answer (score 0):

An Xbox 360 controller is the best bet. If you have an Xbox or friends with one you might be able to get hold of one easy. The wired controllers are generally cheaper but you can get a wireless receiver for the PC to use the wireless ones that tend to come with the consoles.

They are a good investment as they are by far the most supported controller type on PC.

Answer (score -1):

Any gamepad that Windows supports.

So if you have a gamepad driver for the Wiimote-Nunchuck combo (which uses Bluetooth), you're good to go. Some links to get you started (that I did not exhaustively test though):

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35470/how-to-use-your-wii-remote-as-a-gyroscopic-mouse/
http://forums.dolphin-emulator.com/showthread.php?tid=15128
http://www.tested.com/news/how-to-make-console-gamepads-play-nice-with-pc-and-mac/203/